# RabbitMQ how to optimally publish/consume messages in a cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am just curious what is the optimal way to publish and consume messages, ignoring durability, persistence and similar things, but rather from the network perspective in a cluster?

If we publish a message over a connection opened to server 1 (s1), but the queues `master-locator-node` is on server 2 (s2), the server has to move that message from s1 to s2, right?

It would be optimal to always consume from queues that are "local" to the server we are connected on, meaning that all the queues we consume from over our connection are located on that server, wouldn't it?

Is this overcomplicating? Or would it be best to always publish to and consume from servers where the queue is located? I am dealing with somewhere around 3B messages daily, so I am trying to reduce latency and load as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, always publishing to and consuming from the queue master node is optimal. Your understanding of what happens when you connect to a non-master node is correct. Of course, this means you will have to make your applications aware of this information (from the HTTP API).

If you're not worried about message loss, there's little need for a cluster in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually a really good point, I might have to rethink if I even need a cluster (maybe a failover server would be better).

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring important factors of the correct guidance, such as persistence and message size.Depending on message size , persistence and workload you have three potential resource bottlenecks 1) CPU 2) Network 3) Storage. In addition there is also the possibility of a contention bottleneck depending on the number of clients on each queue.

Comment: I am not ignoring persistence, I just didn't want to overcomplicate my question, I am using non-persistent messages, my queues have max-messages argument set and I am using no-ack, I am ok with losing messages. I was wondering more about how servers in a cluster transfer messages. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: They don't , they redirect requests from consumers. (typically) If the messages non persistent with no ordering requirements then "round robin" is typically used